# Python com socket comunicação entre computadores

Tags: python, socket

Alguém sabe como conectar vários computadores com socket no Python, estou criando uma pequena Blockchain de teste e quero distribuir os arquivos entre todas as maquinas conectadas através do socket, quero criar um P2P, quero saber a logica para criar uma conexão para que todos si comuniquem com todos, sincronizado, da uma força alguém, não acho esse tipo de informação em nenhum lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um motivo por que inventaram HTTP por cima de comunicação pr sockets, e depois XMLRPC e JSONRPC por cima do HTTP - sckets proveem uma comunicação de baixo nível - você tem que se preocupar com muitos detalhes, a começar de aceitar a comunicação e continuar a mesma em outra thread/processo/tarefa async, para não bloquear o servidor.

A melhor coisa que você faz é usar um protocolo de mais alto nivel do que sockets, e aí você pode se preocupar com o seu problema específico sem ficar re-inventando a roda - acredito que o framework Flask, possivelmente com uma extensão para facilitar APIs Rest para comunicações server-side e requests para a parte de cliente, para  a parte de comunicação entre nós do seu projeto.

Uma explicação detalhada de como fazer a comunicação p2p via sockets da forma correta seria no mínimo equivalente a um capítulo de livro, e, sem nenhum código seu para olhar, certamente está fora do escopo deste site.

(Lembrando que para um projeto de blockchain a parte de redes pode ser a mais simples - eu tenho um projeto justamente sem  a parte de rede, que está no github - se interessar fique a vontade para pegar coisas de lá ou construir a partir dele - https://github.com/jsbueno/pythonchain )

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, então o problema do meu projeto e o uso do socket que e de baixo nível, eu teria que usar um websocket talvez algo mais alto nível.

Comment: isso - uma API REST comum com flask pode ser o suficiente  - uma blockchain não depende muito de _como a comunicação é feita entre os nós, mas sim de que os dados sejam consistentes entre os nós depois de terem sido transmitidos - a rede do bitcoin mesmo tem múltiplos protocolos de rede, e depende da configuração de cada full node como é o acesso a outros nós. Esta resposta tem mais informações: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79167/why-doesn-t-bitcoin-use-udp-to-do-blockpropagation